# qcombobox placed on wrong mouse position in qgraphicsscene

Tags: qgraphicsscene, qcombobox

Im trying to create a combobox in Qgraphicsscene at the mouse position when spacebar is press. but combobox doesnt seems to be placed in the right position. Please help me. Here is my code

```
class ConsoleScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConsoleScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.node_menu = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space and not self.node_menu:
            self.node_menu = QtWidget.QCombobox()
            view = self.views()[0]
            pos = view.mapToGlobal(view.mapToGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos()))
            self.addWidget(self.node_menu)
            self.node_menu.move(pos.x(), pos.y())
            self.node_menu.setFocus(True)
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape and self.node_menu:
            self.node_menu.deleteLater()
            self.node_menu = None
        super(ConsoleScene, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

PS:- This doesnt work windows 10, python 3.0, PyQt5
     though it works on Linux, python 2.7, PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

So after going through the QCursor document, I found

```
pos = view.mapToGlobal(view.mapToGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos()))
```

should be

```
pos = view.mapToGlobal(view.**mapFromGlobal**(QtGui.QCursor.pos()))
```

"mapFromGlobal" translates mouse position to widget coordinates.
*it is also important that you "setSceneRect" or it wouldn't work*